# `Uncaught Error: Map container is being reused by another instance` from second manual search

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am currently trying to make an IP address checker which checks user's ip on load and on the user's manual search using Leaflet and other apis like ipgeolocation and currencyconverer. Currently, the map loads perfectly on load and on the first manual search after load. But when I try to do the second manual IP search I get this -

```
Map.js:745 Uncaught Error: Map container is being reused by another instance
at i.remove (Map.js:745:10)
at HTMLButtonElement.mapOff (index.js:136:25)
```

and then the result shows up like the first search.
**Why is it appearing and how do I solve it?**

**Github Repository Link** - https://github.com/MustakAbsarKhan/ip-address-tracker

Code-

```
//loading map and it's features
        mapload ();
            
        function mapload (){
            count++;
            if(count===1){
                //map initiation
                var map = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
                
            }else if(count === 2){
                
                var map = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
                count --;
            }

            //maptile setup
            L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=Kiarb32YtKIgXk1i9lL1',{
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1,
                minZoom: 1,
                attribution: "\u003ca href=\"https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; MapTiler\u003c/a\u003e \u003ca href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\" target=\"_blank\"\u003e\u0026copy; OpenStreetMap contributors\u003c/a\u003e",
                crossOrigin: true
            }).addTo(map); 

            //map icon
            var blackIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'images/icon-location.svg',
                iconSize: [30, 40]
            });

            //marker & popup on marker
            L.marker([latitude, longitude],{icon: blackIcon}).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup('Your IP Shows You Here')
            .openPopup();

            //popup on map click
            var popup = L.popup();

            function onMapClick(e) {
                popup
                    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
                    .openOn(map);
            }
            map.on('click', onMapClick);

            //leaflet-locatecontrol plugin
            var lc = L.control.locate({
                position: 'topleft',
                tap: false,
                strings: {
                    title: "Click here, to get your device's current location"
                },
                locateOptions: {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            }).addTo(map);
            count--;
            
            function mapOff(){
                map.off();
                map.remove();
            };

            button.addEventListener('click',mapOff);
        };
```

Comment: Please share initializing the map part of the code at least.

Comment: Added the portion of code related to the map. Please check.

Comment: You can define `var map = undefined` globally and then call `mapload();` only if `map === undefined` .

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.

Comment: Nice! Let others know how did you solve it .

Comment: I have solved the issue by separating the marker, making the code only reposition the marker if the map and layer are already defined. The thing that did cause the problem was- The map and Its Layer Container were getting initialized over and over following the button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by **separating the marker**, making the code only reposition the marker if the map and layer are already defined.
The thing that did cause the problem was- The map and Its Layer Container were getting initialized over and over following the button click.
Hope someone in the future will find this solution useful.

The Code-

```
let count = 0;

ipgeolocationapiCALL(ipgeolocationAPI);

  //if user clicks on the button
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (searchbox.value !== "") {
      ipgeolocationAPI =
        `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?${params}&ip=` + searchbox.value;
      count++;
      ipgeolocationapiCALL(ipgeolocationAPI);
    };
  });

  //initialization of map on load cause the count value stays 0 at the beginning and when the search icon is pressed for the first time
  function initializeMap(latitude, longitude) {
    map = L.map("map").setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
    L.tileLayer(
      "https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=Kiarb32YtKIgXk1i9lL1",
      {
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        minZoom: 1,
        attribution:
          '\u003ca href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank"\u003e\u0026copy; MapTiler\u003c/a\u003e \u003ca href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank"\u003e\u0026copy; OpenStreetMap contributors\u003c/a\u003e',
        crossOrigin: true,
      }
    ).addTo(map);
    var blackIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "images/icon-location.svg",
      iconSize: [30, 40],
    });
    L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon: blackIcon })
      .addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("Your IP Shows You Here")
      .openPopup();
    L.control
      .locate({
        position: "topleft",
        tap: false,
        strings: {
          title: "Click here, to get your device's current location",
        },
        locateOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
        },
      })
      .addTo(map);
  }

  function ipgeolocationapiCALL(api) {
    //returns "ip": "103.145.74.149","continent_code": "AS","continent_name": "Asia","country_code2": "BD","country_code3": "BGD","country_name": "Bangladesh","country_capital": "Dhaka","state_prov": "Dhaka Division","district": "Savar Upazila","city": "Savar Union","zipcode": "","latitude": "23.86170","longitude": "90.25649","is_eu": false,"calling_code": "+880","country_tld": ".bd","languages": "bn-BD,en","country_flag": "https://ipgeolocation.io/static/flags/bd_64.png","geoname_id": "1200292","isp": "Master Net","connection_type": "","organization": "Master Net","currency": {"code": "BDT","name": "Bangladeshi Taka","symbol": "৳"},"time_zone": {"name": "Asia/Dhaka","offset": 6,"current_time": "2022-08-28 15:24:16.540+0600","current_time_unix": 1661678656.54,"is_dst": false,"dst_savings": 0
    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json()) //collects data as json
      .then((data) => {
        //declaring contents of api as objects
        const ip = data.ip; //103.145.74.149
        const { city, country_name, isp, country_flag, latitude, longitude } =
          data; //Dhaka, Bangladesh,Master Net
        const { current_time, name } = data.time_zone; //"2022-08-27 23:25:49.527+0600";
        const { code, symbol } = data.currency; //BDT,TAKA SYMBOL

        let timezone = current_time.slice(current_time.length - 5); //+0600
        let date = current_time.slice(0, current_time.search(" ")); // 2022-08-27
        let time = current_time.slice(date.length + 1, date.length + 9); //23:01:28
        let exactTimezone =
          "UTC " +
          timezone.slice(0, 3) +
          ":" +
          timezone.slice(timezone.length - 2, timezone.length); //UTC +06:00

        //assigning api values to html elements
        ipAddress.textContent = ip;
        cityData.textContent = city + ",";
        countryData.textContent = country_name;
        timezoneData.textContent = exactTimezone + ",";
        timeData.textContent = time + ",";
        dateData.textContent = date;
        ispData.textContent = isp;
        currencyData.textContent = code + ` (${symbol})`;
        flagIcon.src = country_flag;
        let currencyCODE = code; //assigining fetched value to this variable for being able to reassign value to following conditions
        if (currencyCODE === "USD") {
          currencyCODE = "EUR";
          let xchangeRateAPI = `https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from=USD&to=${currencyCODE}`;
          xchangeRateAPICALL(xchangeRateAPI);
        } else {
          let xchangeRateAPI = `https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from=USD&to=${currencyCODE}`;
          xchangeRateAPICALL(xchangeRateAPI);
        }

        //calling exchange rate api. This one Converts USD to User's Currency and For users who lives in United States it would convert 1 USD to Euro.
        function xchangeRateAPICALL(api) {
          fetch(api)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              const { to } = data.query;
              const { result } = data;
              const convertedAmount = result.toFixed(2);
              currencyconvertData.textContent =
                "$ 1 = " + `${to} ${convertedAmount}`;
            });
        }

        //default value of count is 0 which gets incremented in the previous if function(which checks if the input field has any value)
        if (count === 0) {//initializing the map and the layout on load
          initializeMap(latitude, longitude);
        } else {//resetting the marker position as the map and layout is already initialized
          var blackIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: "images/icon-location.svg",
            iconSize: [30, 40],
          });
          L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon: blackIcon })
            .addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("Your IP Shows You Here")
            .openPopup();
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error is "+ error);
        alert("Wrong IP. Please Try Again.");
        searchbox.value = "";
      });
```